# How to format numeric datagridview cell after edit

Tags: winforms, datagridview, formatting

Datagridview is unbound. two columns contain numeric values and the C2 format is applied to those columns. The grid displays such as $3,200.00. I edit the value and move away from the cell. The end edit event fires and a routine is called to save the data to SQL. I would like to know how to return the cell to the currency format after the edit ends.

I have tried the suggestion in the suggested post with no success.

If I enter 1234 I expect it to display $1,234.00 but it displays 1234.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, it sounds as though you did not set the column's `ValueType` property.  If you do not set this property, the default type is `String`. Since you are displaying currency values, `Decimal` would be the proper type to set.

```
DataGridView1.Columns(0).ValueType = GetType(Decimal)
```